# TCP recv and receiving buffered

Tags: c, sockets, recv, tcpsocket

I have a problem with my network application project.

This is the part of my principal structure :

```
    struct elemento 
    { 
        char username[256]; 
        short int UDPport;
        unsigned long IPaddress;
        int socket; 
        char buffer[256];
        int last; 
        struct elemento *next; //puntatore all'elemento successivo della lista
        struct elemento *enemy; //puntatore alla struttura dell'avversario
    };

typedef struct elemento player; 


player *client = NULL; //punta al client attualmente gestito
```

This is the function that handle the return value of recv

```
int recvTCP(int sd, void* buf, int len)  
{
  int ret;
  ret = recv(sd,buf,len,0);
  if (ret<len)
 {
    if(ret==0)  
    {
        /
        FD_CLR(sd,&master); 
        close(sd); //chiudo la socket
        printf("%s si è disconnesso dal server\n",client->username);
        if(client->impegnato==YES)  
        {
            //notifica(client->enemy->socket);
        }
        if(client->ready==YES)
        {
            numerogiocatori--; 
        }
        elem_remove(client); 
        return -1; 
    }

    return ret; 

}
return 0; 
 }
```

and this is the function that handle the buffering of the data :

```
int riceviMsg()
{
    int ret;
    ret = recvTCP(client->socket,&(client->buffer[client->last]),client->length);
    if(ret<0) return -1; 
    if(ret==0) 
    {
        client->last=0; 
        return 0; 
    }
    client->last=ret;
    client->length=(client->length)-(client->last);  
    return ret;
}
```

and this is the function that handling the recv of INT variable :

```
int riceviLength() 
{

  int ret;
  int temp; 
  ret = recvTCP(client->socket,&temp,4-client->last);
  client->length=(client->length)<<(8*(ret)); 
  client->length=(client->length)|temp;  
  if(ret<0) return -1; 
  if (ret==0)  
  {
    client->last=0;
    return 0;
  }
  client->last=client->last-ret;
  return ret;
}
```

I suppose that this last one is completely wrong. I say suppose because I'm trying the app in localhost and is much rare to receive only partial data ..

And on riceviMsg() I have this doubt :

if I send "ciao\0" , on the other side the recv which letter receives for first ?  "c" or "\0" ?

Thanks to everybody :)

P.s : I think that I will send the lenght of the data after converting it to string and I will handle it using riceviMsg() function. I will delete riceviLenght() because it's completely wrong. 
But now I don't know if the buffer on riceviMsg() correctly works :/

Comment: There's some things that make no sense here... What are you trying to accomplish with `client->length=(client->length)<<(8*(ret));` and with `client->last=client->last-ret;` ?

Comment: I tried to shift to the left the partial integer previously read and add to it the new part of int that arrives.
But now I suppose that I will send the lenght of the data after converting it to string and I will handle it using riceviMsg() function
But I don't know if the buffer on riceviMsg() correctly works :/

Comment: But as you receive more data you're lowering `client->last` while the call to `recvTCP` seems to assume it's growing with more data...

Comment: Switching to a text protocol is probably a good idea anyhow.

Comment: text protocol is a good idea ? 
I will use sprintf to convert integer in a string. 
An integer is 4byte therefore have I to use 5 byte string right ?
example : 0001/0